# Access a part of a string in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I receive the following token value from the following line of code.

```
mytoken = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

```
// The contents of mytoken is as the following.
// This is what the debug window shows me
mytoken = "{\"token\":\"R6ZdGByrEguKvYGyfHZRgMzabdynQgPY.\",\"validity\":true}"
```

I tried to access the contents of mytoken by using `mytoken["token"]` but this does not seem to work. Am I missing something here? Do I need to deserialize the string first?

I would like to have the final result in another variable such as this.

```
result = "R6ZdGByrEguKvYGyfHZRgMzabdynQgPY."
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `mytoken` is a string, which is representing some json object.  However, the json you posted as an example is not valid json...

Comment: A screenshot of `mytoken` in the debugger watch window, or of `Console.WriteLine(mytoken);`, would ordinarily be out of order, but I think in this case it might be helpful.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I updated it with the debug window values

Comment: @maccettura Please see my recent edits.

Comment: @Anna ok now your JSON looks valid.  What you should do is create a class that represents that object (a string token property and a boolean validity property).  Then you can _deserialize_ your JSON into an actual C# object (use JSON.NET or the new .NET Core 3 JSON libraries)

Comment: @maccettura I could use a class structure for it. Is get; and set; sufficient for it?

Comment: @Anna Jason's answer allows for a more loose approach, if you want to parse/deserialize into a custom defined object you need to make a class with the two properties (`"token"` and `"validity"`).  You can shorthand property declarations as `public string Token { get; set; }`

Comment: @maccettura I actually created a class as you mentioned and it works well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a JSON string.  You need to use a [JSON parser](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParsingLINQtoJSON.htm) to read it

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(mytoken);

var result = o["token"].Value;
```